# Sort Pandas dataframe by list size not A-Z

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
username          group
user1             [A]
user2             [B, C]
user3             [A, B, C]
user4             [A, B]
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
username          group
user3             [A, B, C]
user4             [A, B]
user2             [B, C]
user1             [A]
```

I've looked up the documentation for sort_values and it seems to cover mainly 0-9 or A-Z sorting.. thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @rje, new to stackoverflow so didn't know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to create a new column with the lengths and then sort by that:

```
df['len'] = df['group'].str.len()
df.sort_values(by='len', ascending=False).drop(columns='len')
```

the output is:

```
    group       
2   (A, B, C)   
1   (B, C)      
3   (A, B)      
0   (A,)
```

Comment: df['group'].str.len()

Comment: @Wen, you are correct, that is actually a better solution, will change this

Comment: @Wen actually not, think `len(str([100, 100]))` vs `len(str([1, 2, 3]))`

Comment: It baffles me that this sophisticated library apparently can't add a `key` argument accepting a callable...

Comment: thank you!  any way to hide the len column after i've done sort_values?

Comment: For me `.apply(len)` is slightly faster than `.str.len`, if I concatenate until it's 40M rows, it's 12.7s versus 13.7s. Not anything special.

Comment: @DerrickSong `df.drop(columns='len', inplace=True)`

Comment: @timgeb It's because DataFrames aren't designed to store arbitrary python objects. Just because you *can* put a list in a DataFrame doesn't mean that you *should*. They're not optimized for that.

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón you're confusing the uses. What you're calculating would be the equivalent of `df.group.astype(str).str.len()`, but `df.group.str.len()` will computer the number of elements in a list if it receives a list.

Comment: @timgeb it seems it's a feature request that's been open for a while, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3942

Comment: @ALollz Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @PMende My point was about custom sorting, not about lists in dataframes. I want a `key` argument to sort numeric data or strings by a custom criterion.

Comment: @timgeb I think the most `pandorable` equivalent is a combination of `assign` (where you would place your `key`), `sort_values`, and `drop` in a method chain. Either way, a temporary array must be made. If not, you're pushing computation to python, even for strictly numeric columns (which is obviously not what you want to be doing)

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing it out there as an option:

```
df.reindex(df['group'].str.len().sort_values(ascending=False).index)
```

Comment: I kind of like this approach. But it's also quite hard to read. And I'm thinking it's probably slower because you do a sort and then a reindex.. still cool though

Answer (score 1):

More gentle way by using `keys` of `sort_values`

```py
df.sort_values(by='group', key=lambda x: x.str.len(), ascending=False)
```

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A": [[0, 1], [3], [1, 4, 5]]})
df

    A
0   [0, 1]
1   [3]
2   [1, 4, 5]

df.sort_values(by="A",  key=lambda x: x.str.len(), ascending=False)

    A
2   [1, 4, 5]
0   [0, 1]
1   [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a column to your dataframe that stores the length of the lists, and then sorting:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A": [[0, 1], [3], [1, 4, 5]]})
#            A
# 0     [0, 1]
# 1        [3]
# 2  [1, 4, 5]

df["Length"] = df["A"].str.len()

df.sort_values("Length", ascending=False)
#            A  Length
# 2  [1, 4, 5]       3
# 0     [0, 1]       2
# 1        [3]       1
```

If you don't need the `Length` column anymore, you can delete it:

```
df.sort_values("Length", inplace=True, ascending=False)
del df["Length"]
```

Result:

```
           A
2  [1, 4, 5]
0     [0, 1]
1        [3]
```